# Can we use a header file without specifying its .h extension

Tags: c, function, include

For example ,we can use `#include<stdio>`instead of `#include<stdio.h>` in c , And can we used user defined function as a header file without specifying its extension,and add a file with .mp3 extension.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Are those 3 separate questions or just one question? Also what does "user defined function without specifying its extension" mean? Functions do not have extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, [can we] use `#include<stdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`

In theory, yes, a compiler could provide that feature.  In practice, no, I have never encountered a C compiler that let you do that.

Why do you want to do that?

> can we used user defined function without specifying its extension

I don't understand this question.

> and add a file with .mp3 extension

Nothing stops you from saving your C programs into files with an `.mp3` extension, instead of `.c`, and if you then run a C compiler on those files it'll probably compile them.  But if you try to run a C compiler on a file that actually contains an audio recording in MP3 format, I don't see how that could possibly accomplish anything useful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've tried `gcc something.wav`. `gcc` refuses to do this. If I rename the file to `main.c`, it does try to compile it - and it's not pretty _at all_.

Comment: @Michail Floods of "stray `\NNN` in program", eh?  I know why both of those things happen, but I think I'll just confuse OP even more if I try to explain how (typical Unix) C compilers interpret file extensions in any more detail than I did.

Comment: Maybe in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c) then? If you have the time and inclination to do so.

Comment: @Michail I prefer not to use the chat system.  Are you asking me to explain it to you, or to OP?  I'd answer a more coherent question written by you.  (I only wrote this answer because it was too long to be a comment.)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't really know if the OP is interested in this; I find it interesting. I probably will ask a question then - if I can't find an existing explanation somewhere.

Comment: @michail: you only have to read [this section of the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html), which has a complete list of extensions, followed by a description of the `-x` option. (None of this applies to `#include`, which doesn't care about extensions.)